# c# xml special character encoding

Tags: c#, asp.net, character-encoding

I want load xml documents, but there are special symbols like : `ąčęėįšųū` and i get error `Invalid character in the given encoding.` Question is how to encode this characters before load xml ?

```
// load xml result from Google weather
XDocument xd = XDocument.Load("http://www.google.com/ig/api?weather=vilnius&hl=ru");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would give this a try

```
WebClient cln = new WebClient();
var str = cln.DownloadString("http://www.google.com/ig/api?weather=vilnius&hl=ru");
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(new StringReader(str));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("http://www.google.com/ig/api?weather=vilnius&hl=ru", true))
{
    XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(sr);
}
```

The problem is with the encoding. If you use a StreamReader it should detect what encoding the response is in and then allow you to call XDocument.Load.

Comment: sorry i did not understand what you wanted. the above edit should work.